# Como puedo meter datos con el push a un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo meter datos con el push a un arreglo con un while? porque quiero graficar con canvas y lo único que me falta es meter los valores al arreglo con el push para que me los imprima, aqui esta mi código.

```
var meses = [""];
var valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var consulta = "SELECT * FROM produccion WHERE area AND fecha BETWEEN #"+fecha+"# AND #"+fechaFinal+"#";
tablaRecord.Open(consulta, cadConexion);
while(!tablaRecord.eof){    
    meses.push();

    tablaRecord.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué valor quieres agregar al array?  Aquí: `meses.push();` debes pasar un valor dentro de los paréntesis. Y si lo que lees en el `while` es otro array, lo puedes meter entero dentro de `meses`, haciendo algo así: `var arrNew=meses.concat(elOtroArray);`

Comment: de que manera estas consultando a la BD? que es `tablaRecord`?

Comment: Asi estoy consultando la base de datos: var consulta = "SELECT * FROM produccion WHERE area AND fecha BETWEEN #"+fecha+"# AND #"+fechaFinal+"#";                                                                                     , tablaRecord proviene de esto     tablaRecord.Open(consulta, cadConexion);
que es lo que contiene la consulta y la conexión a la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes incluir los datos a agregar como argumentos de push.

Ejemplo

```js
var meses = []; // Array a llenar
var consulta = ['enero','febrero']; // datos a pasar al array
while(consulta[0]){
  meses.push(consulta[0]); // Agregar primer elemento de la consulta al array a llenar
  consulta.shift(); // Eliminar el primer elemento del array consulta
}
console.info(meses); // Mostrar resultado en la consola
```

Si no quieres usar shift puedes usar un iterador

```js
var meses = []; // Array a llenar
var consulta = ['enero','febrero']; // datos a pasar al array
var i = 0;
while(consulta[i]){
  meses.push(consulta[i]); // Agregar primer elemento de la consulta al array a llenar
  i++; // Incrementamos el iterador
}
console.info(meses); // Mostrar resultado en la consola
```

NOTA: Lo de usar usar shift o un iterador en realidad es irrelevante ya que se está preguntando por push.

Comment: Como le puedo hacer para tomar los datos de la base de datos e imprimirlos en el canvas?

Comment: @MichaRuiz esa parece una pregunta de seguimiento que deberías publicar como una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Ok gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ok gracias.....

Comment: @MichaRuiz Si no lo has hecho aún, por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por qué recorrer un array para poner sus elementos en otro, cuando puedes hacerlo directamente usando [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat).

> El método `concat()` se usa **para unir dos o más arrays**. Este método no
>   cambia los arrays existentes, sino que devuelve un nuevo array.
>
> ---
>
> [<sup>Documentación de MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)

Veamos:

```js
var meses = ['enero']; 
var consulta = ['febrero', 'abril', 'diciembre']; 

/*Creamos un nuevo array combinado*/
var newArr =meses.concat(consulta);

/*Prueba*/
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Y que parametro estara en el push()?

Comment: @MichaRuiz  si lo que quieres es meter todo el array dentro del otro, no necesitas recorrerlo  para ir insertando cada valor uno por uno, lo que hace `concat` es producir un nuevo array que combina los dos  anteriores.